# Run batch/bash command repeatedly over a period with pauses in between

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cmd

To be clear, I'm seeking an implementation of this in both windows command line (batch file) and in a bash shell. Here is what I want to do:

- Run a task/command
- Kill the task after running for 1 hour
- Wait 2 hours, then repeat(loop)

Preferably with a pure implementation in batch/bash. I've looked a bit around, but have not been able to find a solution to this, plus I'm a beginner, so any hints in the right direction will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you need an external application that does that, normally cron on linux and windows task scheduler are very well suited for that kind of tasks. They are also long tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a batch version

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /l %%a in () do (
        start "" myTask.exe
        timeout /t 3600 
        taskkill /im myTask.exe /f
        timeout /t 7200 
    )
```

Create an infinite loop repeating the indicated sequence `start / wait / kill / waitMore`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late response to this, but this works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use something like this in bash :

```
while true 
do
  sleep 3600
  kill task
done
```

Comment: Yes you can! Thanks a lot. This is also a correct answer, but I can unfortunately only mark one as correct..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using cron? You can create a script that runs the command, waits 1 hour and exits, which you can set it to run every 3 hours.